# In Prolog, how to sort even and odd numbers represented with symbols and chains of predicates?

Tags: prolog, knowledge-management

The title might be fuzzy, just see the code

```
number(one, odd).
number(two, even).
number(three, odd).
number(four, even).
number(five, odd).

greaterThan(five, four).
greaterThan(four, three).
greaterThan(three, two).
greaterThan(two, one).

if_larger(A,B):- elder_than(A,B).
if_larger(A,B):- elder_than(A,X),greaterThan(X,B).

even(A):- number(A, even).
odd(A):- number(A, odd).

largest(A):-
    not(greaterThan(_,A)).

largestEven(A):-
    even(A),
    not((if_larger(X,A), even(X))).

largestOdd(A):-
    odd(A),
    not((if_larger(X,A), odd(X))).
```

how to sort the numbers in the following order: one, three, five, two, four.

I think the solution should be in the following form, however I couldn't figure them out.

```
next(A, Next):- 
    odd(A), odd(Next),
    ...

next(A, Next):- 
    even(A), even(Next),
    ...

next(A, Next):- 
    odd(A), even(Next),
    ...
```

Or, is it possible to generate a list, like [one, three, five, two, four].

Comment: Post some attempt you did. BTW you can solve your problem very easily using `findall/3`...

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a more specific question. Also, indicate specifically what kind of query you how to enter and what results you expect.

Comment: @luker , I have added my attempt, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @damianodamiano I have added my attempts, thank you for your advice. Could you give a brief summary on how to use `finadall/3` to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: `findall(OddN, number(OddN, odd), OddNums), findall(EvenN, number(EvenN, even), EvenNums), append(OddNums, EvenNums, Numbers)`.

Comment: @lurker This will only work if the order of the number definitions does not change, which is not generalised.

Comment: @ZhangXinye I agree. But your question doesn't say much about your requirements in regards to the order of number definitions. So how is one to give an accurate answer with inadequate understanding requirements? I simply assumed that you needed them in the order in which they were asserted in your database. Calling out numbers by their name `one`, `two`, etc, is very cumbersome when it comes to numerical ordering, if that's what you need.

Comment: @lurker I have found a solution, and posted as answer. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The idea is using final/3 to construct a list of all the numbers, then apply insertion sort on the numbers list.

Implementation

```
number(five, odd).
number(one, odd).
number(two, even).
number(three, odd).
number(four, even).

greaterThan(five, four).
greaterThan(four, three).
greaterThan(three, two).
greaterThan(two, one).

even(A):- number(A, even).
odd(A):- number(A, odd).

is_larger(A,B):- greaterThan(A,B).
is_larger(A,B):- greaterThan(A,X),is_larger(X,B).

% the order considered even and odd
% which is odd before even, small before large
in_order(A,B):- odd(A), even(B).
in_order(A,B):- odd(A), odd(B), is_larger(B,A).     % smaller numbers comes first
in_order(A,B):- even(A), even(B), is_larger(B,A).   % smaller numbers comes first


% apply insertion sort on A 
insertion_sort(A,B):- sort_helper(A, [], B).
sort_helper([], OldList, OldList).
sort_helper([H|T], OldList, Result):- insert(H, OldList, NewList), sort_helper(T, NewList, Result).

% insert(A,L,Result) put A into L 
insert(A, [], [A]).
insert(A, [H|T], [A,H|T]):- in_order(A,H).
insert(A, [H|T], [H|NewList]):- not(in_order(A,H)), insert(A, T, NewList).

% Interface
oddEvenSortedList(OddEvenSortedList):- findall(A, number(A,_), Numbers), insertion_sort(Numbers, OddEvenSortedList).
```

Result

```
?- ['number.pl'].
true.

?- oddEvenSortedList(OddEvenSortedList).
OddEvenSortedList = [one, three, five, two, four].
```

This question is actually a modified version of my school assignment. The original question is Royal Family Succession in Prolog. I have asked a lot of friends on how to solve this problem, and finally got this solution. I will post the original question here as well.

> The old Royal succession rule states that the throne is passed down along the male line according to the order of birth before the consideration along the female line – similarly according to the order of birth. Queen Elizabeth, the monarch of United Kingdom, has four offsprings; namely:- Prince Charles, Princess Ann, Prince Andrew and Prince Edward – listed in the order of birth.